# disable kendo-ui grid multi column filtering

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to disable kendo-ui grid multi column filtering?
I need to clear other column filter value when filtering with a column, and filtering only possible with single column(Not combination filter)?

Comment: i have updated to the correct github links seams i had problems with previous one. now all should work as expected. Now filterMenuInit event will fire each time you click on the filter button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - **demo:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/disable-kendo-ui-grid-multi-column-filtering

try this:

```
var datasource = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{}],
    filterable : true,
    filterMenuInit: function(e) {
        $("form.k-filter-menu button[type='reset']").trigger("click");
    },
    dataSource: {
        data: [{}]
    }
});
```

> **NOTE:** after some research i noticed that this is a common issue in the kendo community as well as is one of the most wanted feature to **bind the filter menu event**, but still there is no valid fix. so, i decided to hack the source code a little bit (just few lines of code),  this task has been quite annoying since the kendo source is only available in compressed/obfuscated format for non licensed copy, BTW, you can see the result on the demo page and look into the source code. [source on github](https://github.com/aSeptik/kendo) for [direct cdn file inclusion](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aSeptik/kendo/master/kendo-hacked/kendo.all.js) hope this help someone...

Comment: According to "Fired when the grid filter menu is initialized, when it is opened for the first time"
It works just once.

Comment: @ramin_rp i have updated the answer hope this will help you.